# Trying To Compile a TypeScript file in Dockerfile failing

Tags: typescript, docker, dockerfile

I have a React project that includes TypeScript and I want to make sure all the TypeScript is converted to JavaScript.  Specifically, in my route, I have a server.ts file that I compile by typing `tsc server.ts`.  All the other files seem to work automatically (maybe it's WebStorm doing that for me, not sure).

I tried to update my dockerfile to compile server.ts but it's not working.  when I do my docker build, I see the latest TypeScript version echoing but it always says after that server.ts not found.

Please suggest how to update my dockerfile below.

```
FROM node:alpine

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/
RUN npm install
RUN npm install --global ntypescript typescript


# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src

RUN tsc -v
RUN tsc server.ts

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `node:10-alpine` i have same issue and resolve it by updating it